# Why do we take the negative square root in this inverse function?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

$f(x) = 2(x-1.5)^2 + 0.5$ for $x \le 3/2$
Find $f^{-1}(x)$ and state it's domain.

So I'm getting:
 $f^{-1}(x) = [(x-0.5)/2]^{\frac{1}{2}} + 1.5$ for $x ≥ 1/2$
But according to the marking scheme, I'm supposed to take the negative square root, not the positive. Need an explanation. Graphs would be a great help.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is defined for $x\leq \frac32$. You need to make sure that that matches the range of $f^{-1}$. In other words, you want $\frac32$ to be the *largest possible* value you can get from applying $f^{-1}$. That is exactly what happens if you choose
$$
f^{-1}(y) = -\sqrt{\frac{y-0.5}{2}}  +\frac32
$$
whereas if you choose the positive square root, then you wouldn't get the inverse of $f$. You would get the inverse of $g(x)$ defined as
$$
g(x) = 2\left(x-\frac32\right)^2 + \frac12, \quad x\geq \frac32
$$
Here is a simple graph:

[image]

The red part is $f$, but you have found the inverse of the blue part, which is what I called $g$ above.